# How to use XOM to query and manipulate XML tags converted from srcml

Tags: java, xml, xom

Please bear with me. I am newbie to parsing. 
I want to use XOM to query an xml document and modify the code. Example -

```
<expr_stmt><expr><name>x_int</name><operator>=</operator><literal type="number">10</literal></expr>;</expr_stmt>

 <expr_stmt><expr><name>x_char</name><operator>=</operator><literal type="char">'t'</literal></expr>;</expr_stmt>
<expr_stmt><expr><name>x_double</name><operator>=</operator><literal type="number">1.4</literal></expr>;</expr_stmt>
```

So I want to use XOM to query the doc and add an output line after every assignment statement. 
Please bear in mind that you are talking to java, xml, parsing beginner ... so just take it step-by-step .... how to start xom and query xml documents and add statements

Comment: Please don't ask for tutorials. The first hit searching for "xom tutorial" brings up a page called "XOM Tutorial" directly on the XOM home page. Try it yourself and learn how to use a search engine.

Comment: Where do I run it ? I downloaded all the files. How do I even start XOM and enter the commands. I've skimmed through the entire tutorial page and didnt find anything to get me started

Comment: XOM is a library. You include the necessary JAR files into your classpath then write a Java program using the XOM classes. The XOM homepage includes [installation instructions](http://www.xom.nu/install.xhtml). If you are a Java beginner why do you want to use an old (maybe unsupported), non-standard library for XML parsing? There are the standards SAX, DOM and StaX already included in modern JDK with far more support and tutorials out there.